# Excel Rows to Col Power Query

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxYl9.png)

Hi anyone may help wanted to convert data into three columns PO Sales Tax Shipping Total. Kinda stuck anyone can help pciture attached.

let
Source = Folder.Files(path),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".pdf")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "datatabales", each Pdf.Tables([Content])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Content"}),
#"Expanded datatabales" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "datatabales", {"Id", "Name", "Kind", "Data"}, {"Id", "Name.1", "Kind", "Data"}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded datatabales", each Text.Contains([Name.1], "Page0")),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Data"}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Data", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19"}),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Data", each [Column7] = "PO #:" or [Column7] = "Sales Tax:" or [Column7] = "Shipping & Handling:" or [Column7] = "Total:"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows2", {{"Column9", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Column8", "Column9"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"Column10", "Column11", "Column12"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.1"),
#"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Columns1",{"Column7", "Merged", "Merged.1"}),
#"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Removed Other Columns2",{"Merged", "Merged.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.2"),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Merged Columns2","Terms:IMMEDIATE","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Merged.2"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","Terms","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Merged.2"})
in
#"Replaced Value1"